# How to execute more than one background process in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, supervisord

First of all, I know about queues and now have good experience with queues. The problem with the queue is, it is a queue. I want to execute multiple functions or commands together in the background. Queues will keep second command or function in a queue and will execute once the first one is done executing!

For example, I have a table with ~3,000,000 records and I want to process them faster. What I can do is divide them into 5 equal chunks and execute 5 commands altogether so that I can utilize my CPU as well as process data 5 times faster.

So, How can I do this with Laravel? Queues are not going to work because they execute stuff one after another. If your idea is to create multiple 5 multiple queues and supervisors to accomplish, that's not a standard way to do it I think.

Any Idea on what can be done in this case?

Comment: Add more php workers and maybe split your queues in heavy load queues and fast queues so that small jobs don't have to wait on the big ones.

Comment: May be this approach worth to try: https://alfrednutile.info/posts/106

Comment: @DharmaSaputra, Absolutely! Maybe that's what I am looking for.

Comment: I have same requirements and same kind of work.

Comment: @Christophvh, I've found the solution and I've created an answer.

Comment: One queue, multiple workers (using [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/horizon), perhaps). If you need the various tasks to happen in a particular order, use [job chaining](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#job-chaining).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add something from my personal experience.

First [install and configure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration) supervisor for your OS accordingly, following are the confs for linux basaed OS e.g. Ubuntu

**Supervisor confs: (/etc/supervisor/conf.d)**

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/app/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=username
numprocs=25
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
stderr_logfile=/var/www/app/storage/logs/worker.error.log
stdout_logfile=/var/www/app/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Then create [jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#creating-jobs) according to your needs and [dispatch](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#dispatching-jobs).

Supervisor will process jobs simultaneously, in this particular case `25` jobs will be processing at a time.

Answer (score 7):

Finally, I found a solution. It is very very easy. So, Here is how it works.

First of all, I divide records into the number of chunks (For example, 5 chunks. It will divide 3 million items into 5 chunks having 600k items each)

Then, I can push a command to queues that I create instantaneously for the chunks and execute queue worker for that queue only once using `--once` option. To make it simple to understand, Here is the code that I am using.

```
$chunk_id = 0;
foreach($chunks as $chunk){
    // Adding chunk to queue
    Artisan::queue('process:items',[
        'items' => $chunk,
    ])->onQueue('processChunk'.$chunk_id);

    // Executing queue worker only once
    exec('php artisan queue:work --queue=processChunk'.$chunk_id.' --once > storage/logs/process.log &');

    $chunk_id++;
}
```

With `exec` command, we are executing queue worker for the specific queue created for the specific chunk. Also, we've added `&` at the end of the command which forces the command to execute in the background at OS level.

This is how it can be done. I tested it and it is working smoothly! Anything else to improve or are there any drawbacks of using this method?

Comment: why not use supervisord with multiple workers say `numprocs=5` ?

Comment: @TahirRaza, Are you sure it will execute more than one queue jobs simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, I've implemented a system in which I have to make 50 simultaneous requests and I have done this with supervisord. You have to run each process for `--once` and increae the number of workers upto your needs, ofcouse you have to take in account your server capabilities.