# Laravel Jobs and Events processing in same queue worker

Tags: laravel, events, jobs

I'm trying to run a time-intensive process in my jobs queue. I have an event being triggered which sends out a socket command to connected users and I have a job that gets queued after that which can run in the background. Before now, I've never run `php artisan queue:work` and my events system was working flawlessly. Now I'm trying to process my jobs and my events AND jobs are trying to be processed by the same queue worker.
[image]

Here is the code that I use to trigger these:

```
event(new ActivateItemAndUpdateRotation($id));
ChangeStatus::dispatch($id, $status);
```

This is really bad for my performance because the users can change statuses really quickly which needs to be updated rapidly and the jobs can just do their thing as they're able to in the background. I've tried adding the jobs to a specific queue and only running that queue worker, but then the events don't get processed at all. So really I have two questions:

1. how have events been getting processed without running a worker up until now?
2. is it necessary to have two workers running now to process the events and the jobs asynchronously?

Comment: This mighe help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987559/how-to-execute-more-than-one-background-process-in-laravel

Comment: So after checking that link, i think there may be some value in it but i'm having a hard time seeing how I can apply it to my use case. My app is a dashboard where users update their current status every few seconds and this triggers an event to update all other dashboards. The job is just to do some other arbitrary database stuff that isn't directly related to the status changes. So how would chunking things and using different processes in supervisor be applied in my case?

Comment: Any danger that your ActivateItemAndUpdateRotation event implements ShouldQueue?

Comment: no that event implements ShouldBroadcast since it's pushing out on a socket